# Suggested IIS settings for WCF web service?

Tags: wcf, iis, configuration, hosting

I've been reading the documentation on IIS settings, and haven't been able to find much on the MSDN site. I'm trying to figure out the preferred settings for a WCF REST service hosted in IIS6. Main goals of these settings should be reliability, restarting the service when needed, and max throughput.

My service will use some processing power as its converting back and forth from XML, of course. Suggestions, or suggested URLs to read?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've started to find some answers to my own question. I'll post everything I find here.

[Internet Information Services Hosting Best Practices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751802.aspx)

[System.ServiceModel namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731354.aspx)

[serviceHostingEnvironment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731336.aspx)

[How to do away with the .svc file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee358764.aspx)